# count how many times a prime is dividing a number

Tags: java, primes, divide

I'm a beginner, my code finds all the primes that divide a given number but I want it to also print how many times the prime divides.
this is my code:

```
public static void main(){
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    int n = myScanner.nextInt();
    int prime = 2 ;
    int count = 0 ;
    while ( prime <= n ){
        if ( n%prime == 0 ) {
            n = n/prime ;
            System.out.println(prime + " " +count);
        }
        if ( n%prime !=0 ){
            prime = prime + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you'll understand me, thanks!!

Comment: you are not increasing your counter, add "count++;" before the print.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increase the counter:

```
System.out.println(prime + " " +(++count));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the counter for every division that has a remainder `0` 
and you must exit the loop once the remainder is not `0`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    int n = myScanner.nextInt();
    int prime = 2;
    int count = 0;

    while ( prime <= n ){
        if ( n % prime == 0 ) {
            n /= prime;
            count++;
        } else
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(prime + " " +count);
}
```

Comment: it's not exectly what I want, lets say n=100, it prints:
2 1
2 2
5 3
5 5
I want it to print:
2 2
5 2

Comment: @SapirushKalifa did you copy my code or something else?

Comment: What didn't work? Don't you want to print 2 2 when you set number to 100?